# SQLite `explain query plan` shows not every step?

Tags: sql, sqlite

This is some pseudo SQL in which the 'problem' is easily replicated:

```
create table Child (
    childId text primary key,
    some_int int not null
);

create table Person (
    personId text primary key,
    childId text,
    foreign key (childId) references Child (childId) on delete cascade
);

create index Person_childId on Person (childId);

explain query plan select count(1)
                   from Person
                            left outer join Child on Child.childId = Person.childId
                   where Person.childId is null or Child.some_int = 0;
```

The result of the query plan is this:

```
SCAN Person USING COVERING INDEX Person_childId
SEARCH Child USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_Child_1 (childId=?) LEFT-JOIN
```

This looks great right? But I am curious if this is the 'full' plan. This is because `some_int` **does not have an index**. But the query plan does not uncover this, I don't see the filtering anywhere. The database *must* filter on this field right?

When I execute the `some_int` field in a separate query, it shows a `SCAN`, exactly like I though I would see in the previous query plan **because there is no index**:

```
explain query plan select * from Child where some_int = 0;
```

Gives:

```
SCAN Child
```

Now my questions:

- Why isn't there `SCAN Child` shown in the first query plan?
- Why is there a `SCAN` on `Person` and not a `SEARCH`?
- Is the first query plan 'quick' or do I still need to add an index?

Comment: Sqlite uses one index per table in a query. In this case, the automatic one on childId (created because it's the primary key). It looks up specific rows of Child based on the scan of Person.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [this page](https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html). It explains the sqlite query planner in depth and you can find answers to all your questions.
Note that filtering conditions like `WHERE some_int=0` are not displayed in the query plan because they don't affect the plan but only the result set.

In brief:

> Why isn't there SCAN Child shown in the first query plan?

Because, due to the `LEFT JOIN`, sqlite needs to `SCAN Person` and, for every row of Person, use the index on ChildId to find the corresponding records in `Child`.

> Why is there a SCAN on Person and not a SEARCH?

A `SCAN` means reading of all rows of a table, in the order in which they are stored. A `SEARCH` is a lookup of a single value in the table, using an index to find out the rowid and the using the rowid to get to that row of the table, without the need to scan all te table to find the row.
Since your query needs to read all `Person.childId`, it does a full SCAN.

> Is the first query plan 'quick' or do I still need to add an index?

Your query is already using all the indexes it could use, so it's already as fast as you could get it.